# Compare time to milliseconds with date command

Tags: bash, sh, io-redirection

I want to use firefox when a certain time comes. Then came all the processes related to firefox. Time does not compare.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Set time.
realTime=$(date +"%T.%6N")
firstNormalActivityTime=$(date -d 19:06:00.000000 +%s)
secondNormalActivityTime=13:18:00.000000
thirdNormalActivityTime=13:19s:00.000000
#Eternal cycle.
while true
do
    if [ "$realTime" = "$firstNormalActivityTime" ] ; then
    firefox https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-iGuyagMv
    echo "Start normal activity:" >> log.log | date +"%T.%6N" >> log.log
    sleep 5m
    pkill -9 -f firefox
    echo "End normal activity:" >> log.log | date +"%T.%6N" >> log.log
    fi
done
```

Comment: for starters .... after the initial assignments add `typeset -p realTime firstNormalActivityTime secondNormalActivityTime thirdNormalActivityTime`; this will show you the contents of each variable and should explain why your comparison is not 'working'

Comment: `echo "Start normal activity:" >> log.log | date +"%T.%6N" >> log.log` ... the `|` spawns a subprocess to dump the `date` output to `log.log`; there is no need to spawn a subprocess when you can accomplish the same with 2 separate commands, eg, `echo "Start normal activity:" >> log.log ; date +"%T.%6N" >> log.log`

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: `[ "$realTime" = "$firstNormalActivityTime" ]` performs an *exact* string comparison; there's a very good chance this will never match since a) you never recalculate `$realTime` after each pass through the loop (ie, you'll be comparing the same 2 values for the rest of eternity) and b) even if you do recalculate `$readlTime` (on each pass through the loop) you could 'miss' the comparison if the loop is delayed for more than 1 second (eg, OS process scheduling, cpu starvation, etc); you would probably be better off comparing numbers (not strings) and using `-ge` (if both args are nums)

Comment: See ["How to compare two dates in a shell?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84381/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-a-shell).

Comment: `while true; do .... <failed test>; done` will go into a tight cpu-bound loop until the conditional evaluates as true (ie, you're going to tie up an entire cpu thread repeatedly running the loop); to reduce cpu usage you may want to consider having the loop `sleep` after each failed comparison (eg, `sleep 1`, `sleep 0.2`, etc); also consider that even if the conditional succeeds, and you've spawned/killed your firefox process, you'll go right back into an infinite `while` loop (and heavy cpu utilization) ... simply because you have no code that forces a `break` out of the loop

Comment: `%6N` is microseconds not milliseconds. There is a vanishingly small chance that you run the first `date` command at precisely `19:06:00.000000`, so an equally small chance that `$realTime` and `$firstNormalActivityTime` will match given that you never change their values. It is unclear why you believe you need microsecond accuracy to start firefox given that it will probably take over a second to initialise.

Comment: All of the above, and did you really want the `s` char embedded in the seconds field in `thirdNormalActivityTime=13:19s:00.000000` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start `firefox` at a particular time, `at(1)` is designed for this purpose.

```
at 08:00
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at Mon Feb 27 08:00:00 2023
at> DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/firefox 'https://example.org'
at> <EOT>
job 2 at Mon Feb 27 07:00:00 2023
```

```
$ apt-cache show at
Package: at
Version: 3.2.5-1ubuntu1
Installed-Size: 162
[...]
Depends: libpam-runtime (>= 1.0.1-11), lsb-base (>= 3.2-14), libc6 (>= 2.34), libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1), libselinux1 (>= 3.1~)
Homepage: http://blog.calhariz.com
Description-en: Delayed job execution and batch processing
 At and batch read shell commands from standard input
 storing them as a job to be scheduled for execution in the
 future.
 .
 Use
  at    to run the job at a specified time
  batch to run the job when system load levels permit
```